# how to create a node package manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, command-line-interface

my github repository application how to Create mypkgname CLI package manager application

I have registered this package in npm, so I can install it globally:

```
npm install -g mypkgname-cli
mypkgname init myApp
cd myApp
npm install
npm start
```

just examples

- npm install -g mern-cli
- npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: question is not clear. maybe you want to use commander?

Comment: CLI commands for own npm package  just examples                                npm install -g mern-cli  and npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use some cli arg pareser like [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)
or [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

There are many other command line argument parsers.

This tutorial here explains the usage well https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/

Important parts include

- adding `#!/usr/bin/env node` on top of your entry point script.
- in package.json, something like

  `"bin": {
      "mycliapp": "index.js"
  }`
- then running `npm link` or `npm install -g` on your app.